# Esse texto está correto?

Tags: português-brasileiro, ortografia

Texto:

> "Art. 46 - O processo Legislativo municipal compreende a elaboração
>   de:
>
> I - emendas á Lei Orgânica Municipal;
>
> II -Leis Complementares;
>
> III - Leis Ordinárias;
>
> IV - Leis Delegadas;
>
> V - resoluções;
>
> VI - decretos Legislativos. [...]"

Eu vi o texto no site "http://saobernardo.ma.gov.br/transparencia/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/leiorganica-DE-S%C3%83O-BERNARDO.pdf"

Há três pontos que me chamaram a atenção:

nalguns incisos, a primeira letra do texto é maiúscula e noutras, minúscula;

"á" ao invés de "à", eu já vi isso em leis de quando o Brasil era império (Dom Pedro II);

em frente de 1 "-" não há espaço, como há nos outros incisos.

P.S.: inciso é representado por "I-, II-, III-, IV-, V- etc".

O texto é uma lei municipal (SBC), mas me parece esquisita essa desorganização. Por isso eu pergunto: 'tá certo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O **“á” ao invés de *à*** é um erro. A contração da preposição *a* com o artigo *a* era normalmente grafada *á* antes das reformas ortográficas de 1911 em Portugal e 1943 no Brasil; mas a partir de então a ortografia oficial prescreve *à*.

O “**II -Leis**”, é com certeza uma gralha. De qualquer modo, o que deveria ser usado em todos os incisos é uma meia-risca e não um hífen: “II – Leis” e não “II - Leis”; o hífen é para ligar palavras (como em *meia-risca*). O meu Word corrige automaticamente aqui o hífen para meia-risca.

Na questão da **inicial maiúscula ou minúscula** nos incisos, o redator optou por minúscula, mas escreve certos nomes com inicial maiúscula; veja-se que nos incisos II, III e IV a segunda palavra também tem inicial maiúscula (“Leis Complementares”, etc.). O que eu não compreendo é o critério. “Lei Orgânica Municipal” faz sentido com maiúsculas, porque é o nome de uma lei específica. Nos outros casos — “Leis Ordinárias”, “Leis Complementares”, “Leis Delegadas” — trata-se de nomes genéricos. Mas talvez eles tenham uma razão para os tratar diferentemente de “resoluções” e “emendas”.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Jacinto. Explicas muito bem as coisas. Eu tenho sorte de te ter neste site.

Comment: @Schilive, fico satisfeito por te satisfazer. Sabes que não há ninguém melhor para explicar coisas a um principiante do que outro principiante :)